# Writing to JSON file without Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, writetofile

I am already fetching a hard-coded JSON file,

```
 fetch("./dict.json")
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
```

But I would like to add to this already existing file, I have tried a few things such as

```
function setInfo(){
    const new_data = [{
        "email": document.getElementById("email").value,
        "age": document.getElementById("age").value,
        "name": document.getElementById("name").value,
        "password": document.getElementById("password").value
    }]; 
    
    var blob = new Blob([stringify(new_data)], {
        type: 'application/json'
    });

    var anchor = document.createElement('a')
    anchor.download = "dict.json";
    anchor.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    anchor.innerHTML = "download"
    anchor.click();
}
```

But for me, this downloads a new JSON file called dict.json with the new information in it. Can I not reuse the same file?

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot store files on a server without server-side code actually doing that. Otherwise you could randomly vandalize websites by writing to their files.

Comment: What do you mean by server-side code? How do you propose I can do this?

Comment: You're basically simulating a database. People typically use PHP and mySQL or node.js and mongodb or whathaveyou. To properly store persistent data you need a backend language or a db service like Google's firestore. Here's an extensive (php/mysql) tutorial: https://www.positronx.io/build-php-mysql-login-and-user-authentication-system/ (I also recommend using [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/))